# Simple C# and MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I just started learning C# and tried to create a simple project. First I Created a textbox and when someone enters a name in it, the name should show up in the next page but not sure what I'm doing wrong. Textbox and submit button are showing up. After typing the name in the textbox and clicking on submit it doesn't show up in the next page. PLEASE HELP

Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Newproject.Models;

namespace Newproject.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()

    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Welcome(FormCollection form, string CustNo)

    {
       Session["SearchString"] = form["CustNo"];
         ViewBag.Name = Session["SearchString"];
          return View();
    } 
  }
 }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Access TextBox and TextboxFor Value From View To Controller In Asp.net MVC";

}

    <br />
    @Html.Label("Name")
   <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome","Home",FormMethod.Post))
    { 
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", "", new { @class = "CustNo" });
        <br/>
    <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" placeholder="test" type="submit"  onclick = "location.href='@Url.Action("Welcome", "Home", new {})'" />
        <br/>

    }
```

Welcome.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
string CustNo = ViewBag.Name;
 }
   <p> @CustNo</p>
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at `Session["SearchString"] = form["CustNo"];` and see what the value is from the form? These are basic debugging skills you need to learn. You also should be using the "Model" part of MVC instead of relying on ViewBag.

Answer (score 3):

Your input' field's name attribute value is `SearchString`. So you should be looking for that, not `CustNo`. CustNo is the css class name of your input field, You cannot read the value of the input field using the css class name (*unless you are doing some jquery stuff on the form submit*)

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string SearchString)
{  
    ViewBag.Name = SearchString;
    return View();
}
```

Also make sure you are not doing a redirect using javascript when submit button is clicked, but doing a normal form submit.

Simply remove the `onclick` handler. Your button is inside a form and when you click the submit button the form will be submitted (with the form data).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBox("SearchString", "", new { @class = "CustNo" });
   <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" placeholder="test" type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Welcome(FormCollection form)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = form["SearchString"];
        return View();
    } 
}
```

Replace your Html.BeginForm code in Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
  <br />
  <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" />
  <br />
}
```

[image]

Now result:

[image]